# How work menu in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-menu

I read different post, different things and never find the answer. I try to create a simple menu with "..." in the right top corner of my main AppCompatActivity.

I create my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    >

    <item android:title="Settings"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_settings" android:id="@+id/MnuSettings"  />
</menu>
```

I am not able to add this menu to my main AppCompatActivity. I try different thing.

I do in my main "layout activity"

```
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

I try include in my main layout ...

I sure we can add the menu to all the layout but i don't know how and find nothing.

Can somebody help me please.

Did i need to create something in the manifest.xml for the menu. Did i need to add something in the xml of my layout file ... never find the answer .. :-(

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2011/09/how-to-create-android-menus/ and this https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html and probably a thousand others

Answer (score 2):

Suppose your menu xml called `menu_main`. Change it to following,

```
<item android:title="Settings"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_settings" 
    android:id="@+id/MnuSettings"  
    android:title="Settings"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>
```

Then change onCreateOptionsMenu to this

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found what I was searching for in the tutorial bellow.

I was missing the toolbar in my main layout folder

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/SettingToolBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" android:elevation="4dp" android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AlertDialog.AppCompat.Light">
```

After that, I needed this in my OnCreate of my main Activity

```
 Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.SettingToolBar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Lastly
 `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)`  will be called.

Tutorial.

https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html